# Read Google Spreadsheets conditonal format information

Tags: google-sheets-api

I wish to read google spreadsheets conditional format information with script. I do it as below:

```
function readConditionalFormatInfo() {
  var url = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/spreadsheetId?fields=sheets(properties(title,sheetId),conditionalFormats)"
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)
  Logger.log(response)
}
```

But error happen:

```
Request failed for https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/spreadsheetId?fields=sheets(properties(title,sheetId),conditionalFormats) returned code 403. Truncated server response: { "error": { "code": 403, "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.", "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED" } } (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 214, file "Code")
```

Maybe I should not run REST API in GAS but I don't know how to do it in script!

Appreciate if anyone can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like below:

```
function readConditionalFormat() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  if (rules != null) {
    for (var i=0;i<rules.length;i++) {
      var rule = rules[i].getBooleanCondition()
      var criteria = rule.getCriteriaType()
      var value = rule.getCriteriaValues()
      var bakcolor = rule.getBackground()
      Logger.log(criteria+ " -> " + value + ":" + bakcolor);
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('Conditional Format rule null')
  }
}
```